# Xcode5 для разработки до выхода официциальной версии

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

`xcode5` сейчас под  `nda`, тем не менее в последних версиях беты `ioS7` уже есть приложения компилированные `xcode5` (как например `Skype`). Вопрос к тем кто имеет аккаунт разработчика - можно ли уже сейчас выставить в апстор приложение разработанное для `ios7` на `xcode5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С чего вы взяли что Skype собран в Xcode5?

Xcode Developer Preview не может подписывать приложения сертификатом, он выпускается для того чтобы можно было **подготовить** приложение для новой версии ОС.

Comment: В обзоре пятой беты для iOS 7 указывается что в аппсторе приложения готовые для использования в iOS 7 помечены знаком плюса. Каким образом они туда попадают? Они компилированы xcode 4? Если да, то как на аппруве проверяют что приложения для 6.х и 7.х различаются?

Comment: @AlexThumb, затрудняюсь ответить :)